# Parallel code with different output on different machines

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

When I run the code below in two difference machines I get different output, in one the output is correct (sum = sum2) in the other it is not.

and I don't know why

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(){

    const int NX=1000;    
    const int NY=1000;

    float x[NX+2];          
    float y[NX+2];          
    float u[NX+2][NY+2];    

    float x2;   // 
    float y2;
    float sum;
    float sum2;

    for (int i=0; i<NX+2; i++){
      for (int j=0; j<NY+2; j++){
        x2      = i;
        y2      = j;
        u[i][j] = x2+ y2;
        sum += u[i][j];
      }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<NX+2; i++){
      #pragma omp parallel for
      for (int j=0; j<NY+2; j++){
        x2      = i;
        y2      = j;
        u[i][j] = x2+ y2;
      }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<NX+2;i++){
      for (int j=0; j<NY+2; j++){
        sum2 += u[i][j];
      }
    }

    printf("%f \n", sum);
    printf("%f", sum2);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the values of

```
float sum;
float sum2;
```

otherwise when the operations:

```
sum += u[i][j];
```

and

```
sum2 += u[i][j];
```

lead to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). That is why you are see two different results.

Set both variables to zero:

```
float sum = 0;
float sum2 = 0;
```

Compile your code with (at least) the flag  -Wall. If you have done that you would have seen the following warning:

```
main.c:17:7: warning: 'sum2' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   17 | float sum2;
      |       ^~~~
main.c:16:7: warning: 'sum' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   16 | float sum;
      |       ^~~
```

Performance-wise instead of parallelizing the inner loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<NX+2; i++){
   #pragma omp parallel for
   for (int j=0; j<NY+2; j++){
      x2      = i;
      y2      = j;
      u[i][j] = x2+ y2;
    }
}
```

you should profile what happen when you parallelize both loops by using the OpenMP [collapse](https://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/%7Eeijkhout/pcse/html/omp-loop.html#Collapsingnestedloops) option

```
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
for (int i=0; i<NX+2; i++){       
   for (int j=0; j<NY+2; j++){
      u[i][j] = i + j;
    }
}
```

Even if the `collapse` clause is not an opinion (*e.g.,* it is slower), performance-wise it would still be better to parallelize the outer loop rather than the inner loop. First, you avoid the overhead of creating the parallel region `NX+2` times. Second, since the outer loop is iterating over columns and the inner loop over the rows, dividing the iterations of the first loop among threads reduces the likelihood of [false-sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing).

Moreover, you can also parallelize the other two loops. However, you will need to use [OpenMP reduction clause](https://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/%7Eeijkhout/pcse/html/omp-reduction.html#Built-inreductionoperators) to avoid the race-condition during the updates of the sum and sum2 variables.

The final code would look like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(){

   const int NX=1000;    
   const int NY=1000;
   
   float u[NX+2][NY+2];    
   float sum = 0;
   float sum2 = 0;

   #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
   for (int i=0; i<NX+2; i++){
     for (int j=0; j<NY+2; j++){
       sum += i+j;
     }
   }
   #pragma omp parallel for
   for (int i=0; i<NX+2; i++){
     for (int j=0; j<NY+2; j++){
        u[i][j] = i+j;
     }
   }

   #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum2)
   for (int i=0; i<NX+2;i++){
     for (int j=0; j<NY+2; j++){
       sum2 += u[i][j];
     }
   }

   printf("%f \n", sum);
   printf("%f", sum2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response!